# Can a logically false proposition be a logical consequence of anything? (Concerning the semantic definition of logical consequence)

Tags: logic

if i have a proposition that is always false under a given valuation, is it a semantic consequence of anything? in case the antecedent is also logically false,  the  conditions of logical entailment are apparently met ( if the antecedent is true, the consequent is true). Intuition tells me it is the case, but i can't find an example like this anywhere.

Comment: Yes, if the premises is also a contradiction, i.e. a proposition that is always false.

Comment: See [Ex falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Semantic_argument) : a proposition $\varphi$ whatever is semantic consequence of a contradiction. Thus also a proposition always false is.

Comment: so if i have for example (p or q) |= r then both p |= r and q |= r?

Comment: @iamuma. Rephrase your last questions in terms of truth sets, using the following definition : the truth set of (P OR Q) is the union of the truth set of P and of the truth set of Q.  So if  the union of set X and set Y  is included in set Z, is set X included in set Z? is set Y included in set Z? ( You can use a Venn diagram to answer these two questions and after that apply the result to your " logical consequence" problem).

Comment: Not clear... Neither (p or q) nor r are "always 0".

Comment: Maybe you have to read again the def of [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models).

Answer (score 1):

In order B to be a logical consequence of A, it is sufficient and necessary that :

**the set of all valuations in which A is true be included in the set of all valuations in which B is true.**

Remark : this "set of all valuations..." is sometimes called the **truth set** of a proposiiton

Now suppose a proposition Y ( for example  the formula : (AvB) & (~A&~B) ) is false in all valuations.**The set of valuations in which it is true is: the empty set.**

So, in order Y to be a logical consequence of a given proposition, say X, it is therefore required that :

**the set of valuations in which X is true be included in the empty set** ( since , by hypothesis, the " truth set " of Y is the empty set).

But the only set that is included in the empty set is the empty set itself!

So the truth set of X has to be the empty set, in other words, X has to be false in all valuations.

Conclusion : **a logically false proposition can only be a logical consequence of a logically false proposition;** when the conclusion of a reasoning is a logically false proposition, the reasoning is valid if and only if the conjunction of the premises (P1&P2&P3...) is logically false.

So the following reasoning is valid :

(1) (A --> B)

(2) (A & ~B)

(3) Therefore : (AvB) & (~A&~B)

because the truth set of the conjunction of the premises, that is of : 
[(A-->B)& (A&~B)]  is the empty set.

Same thing for the reasoning. 
(1) (A&~A)
(2) Therefore: (B v A)

Remark. I said only a *logically* false proposition can imply logically a logically false proposition; a proposition that is simply false ( but not logically, not "necessaily false", not contradictory) does not imply any logically false proposition, for the truth set of a contingently false proposition ( false relatively to the facts of the world) is not the empty set: there are possible situations in which our proposition would have been true. Consequently, its truth set cannot be included in the truth set of the conclusion in case this conclusion has an empty truth set.

Remark. Note that, while a logically false proposition cannot play the role of conclusion in a valid reasoning whose premises are not logically false ( either individually or at least taken in conjunction) , **a logically false proposition, when used as premise, makes the reasoning in which it is used automatically valid** ( whatever the conclusion may be).

The reason is that the empty set ( i.e. the truth set of a logically false proposition) is included in any set, and therefore, is automatically included in the truth set of the conclusion.